# Use data-attribute for form action?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, custom-data-attribute

I have a client who really hates captcha but it is needed otherwise there are too many spam submissions. I had a person recommend the following:

> Have your web form and only have the form action in a data tag (html5) and then on completion of the form and submit the form process actions that action in. No form action, no bot can fill it in and submit and no modification to how your form looks or operates.

If I have a form that looks like this:

```
<form action="/FormProcessv2.aspx?WebFormID=10090&amp;OID={module_oid}&amp;OTYPE={module_otype}&amp;EID={module_eid}&amp;CID={module_cid}" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return checkWholeForm15174(this)" method="post" name="catwebformform15174">
```

How would I modify the action URL to use data-attribute? Would it require JS to function? How does the idea work?

Note: I searched Google and I could not find any information on using data-attribute and from action. Also I am using jQuery 2.0.3 on the site.

Any guidance is welcome.

Comment: Yes, it would require Javascript. But I wouldn't be surprised if bots are smart enough to bandle that.

Comment: @AndrewBarber - I have actually found many bots are not executing javascript as it slows them down for scanning the page. Do you have an example of how this would work or can point me to a place with information? Also if I can get this working I will put it to the test and see how spam submission goes and can report back as an edit or comment.

Comment: That idea sounds half-baked.  I'm not sure how hiding the action in a data-attribute and then swapping it out when the form is submitted circumvents a bot at all. Most bots will probably try submitting the form themselves but also by simply calling the same code your form does when submitting, which will also "unlock" your hidden action.l

Comment: @AndrewBarber - As an update the spam submissions have gone from 50-100 a day to 0! While I know it isn't full proof it has helped prevent the spam on my site. =>

Comment: Cool; sounds like it was definitely worth it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How it would work, on form submit (call this swapAction when your current checkWholeForm15174 validates)

```
function SwapAction() {
    var dataAttr = $('#myFormName').data();

    $('#myFormName').get(0).setAttribute('action', dataAttr.action);
}
```

assuming your form was modified to look like:

```
<form action="" data-action="/FormProcessv2.aspx?WebFormID=10090&amp;OID={module_oid}&amp;OTYPE={module_otype}&amp;EID={module_eid}&amp;CID={module_cid}"  enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return checkWholeForm15174(this)" method="post" name="catwebformform15174">
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could write that like this: `$('#myFormName')[0].action = dataAttr.action;`

Comment: yessiree, pulled some older code from an older SO post methinks... :-)

Comment: Thank you for the help. I used @ultraviol3tlux method for script. Also my spam has gone to zero! While I know it isn't full proof it is working. Thank you again for the help.